# _tkinter.TclError: no such file or directory

Tags: python, tkinter

The following code intends to use an image "mole.png" for a tkinter button

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import PhotoImage


class whackAMole:
    numMolesAcross = 4
    statusBg = "white"

    def __init__(self):
        self.window = tk.Tk()
        self.moleFrame, self.statusFrame = self.createFrames()
        self.molePhoto = PhotoImage(file = "mole.png")
        self.moleButtons = self.createMoles() #a list of mole buttons
        self.hitCounter, self.missCounter, self.startButton \
        = self.createStatusWidgets()


    def createFrames(self):
        moleFrame = tk.Frame(self.window, width = 300, height = 300, 
                             bg = "grey") #ttk doesn't support bg
        moleFrame.grid(row = 0, column = 0)

        statusFrame = tk.Frame(self.window, width = 100, height = 300, 
                                bg = "red")
        statusFrame.grid(row = 0, column = 1)

        return moleFrame, statusFrame

    def createMoles(self):
        moleButtons = []
        for row in range(numMolesAcross):
            rowOfMoleButtons = []
            for col in range(numMolesAcross):
                mole = tk.Button(self.moleFrame, image = self.molePhoto)
                mole.grid(row = row, column = col)
                rowOfMoleButtons.append(mole)
            moeButtons.append(rowOfMoleButtons)

program = whackAMole()
program.window.mainloop()
```

When I ran this script, I got the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Me/Desktop/whackAMole.py", line 40, in <module>
    program = whackAMole()
  File "/Users/Me/Desktop/whackAMole.py", line 13, in __init__
    self.molePhoto = PhotoImage(file = "/Users/Me/Desktop/mole.png ")
  File "/Users/Me/anaconda/lib/python3.6/tkinter/__init__.py", line 3539, in __init__
    Image.__init__(self, 'photo', name, cnf, master, **kw)
  File "/Users/Me/anaconda/lib/python3.6/tkinter/__init__.py", line 3495, in __init__
    self.tk.call(('image', 'create', imgtype, name,) + options)
_tkinter.TclError: couldn't open "/Users/Me/Desktop/mole.png ": no such file or directory
```

I'm pretty sure both the .py file and the image file are on the desktop. How can I solve this problem? Thank you!

Comment: "pretty sure"? You need to be certain. Python will not typically report that a file doesn't exist unless it really doesn't exist. The very first think you need to do is verify for certain whether `/users/Me/Desktop/mole.png` exists or not. What happens when you type `ls /Users/Me/Desktop/mole.png` from a command prompt?

Comment: Ah...I mean I'm certain. That command gave me an error: 
Error in handling magic function:
  [Errno 20] Not a directory: '/Users/Me/Desktop/mole.png'
  line 232 in /Applications/pyzo.app/Contents/MacOS/source/pyzo/pyzokernel/magic.py